# Unable to load pmml file using pypmml on Windows. Getting FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen, pmml

I tried to install and use [pypmml](https://pypi.org/project/pypmml/) library to open and score a pmml file. I'm using jupyter notebook on Windows. When I'm running this code - `model = Model.load('single_iris_dectree.xml')`, I'm getting below error. But if I try to run it on Mac, it's running absolutely fine. Is there another way to load and score pmml file?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-00bc89b72cd3> in <module>
----> 1 a = Model.load(p)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypmml\model.py in load(cls, f)
    227             # Check if a file path
    228             if os.path.exists(model_content):
--> 229                 model = cls.fromFile(model_content)
    230             else:
    231                 model = cls.fromString(model_content)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypmml\model.py in fromFile(cls, name)
    183     def fromFile(cls, name):
    184         """Load a model from PMML file with given pathname"""
--> 185         pc = PMMLContext.getOrCreate()
    186         try:
    187             java_model = pc._jvm.org.pmml4s.model.Model.fromFile(name)
```

........

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(port, jarpath, classpath, javaopts, die_on_exit, redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr, daemonize_redirect, java_path, create_new_process_group, enable_auth, cwd, return_proc)
    326 
    327     proc = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=stderr,
--> 328                  cwd=kwargs.get('cwd',None), **popen_kwargs)
    329 
    330     # Determine which port the server started on (needed to support

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    798                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:
    802             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1205                                          env,
   1206                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1207                                          startupinfo)
   1208             finally:
   1209                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Could you check if your computer installed Java? PyPMML is the Python API of PMML4S written in Scala/Java, so PyPMML depends on Java to make predictions of PMML models. You need to make sure the java command in PATH or set correct JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I installed JAVA and also reinstalled anaconda. Now it's working fine. Thanks.